# How to implement Chebyshev 2 filter in Python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have Data Like this:
PPG       Timer
1883655   00:01
1884568   00:02
1883677   00:03
1883648   00:04

I want to implement a 4th order chebyshev2 filter for the above PPG data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
b, a = signal.cheby2(4, 40, [0.1, 0.8], 'band', analog=False)

w, h = signal.freqs(b, a)

sos = signal.cheby2(12, 20, [0.1,0.8], 'bp', fs=300, output='sos')

filtered = signal.sosfilt(sos, ppg_data)
```